# How can I complete "Omega: Packages For Ish"?

Tags: mass-effect-2

In the assignment **Omega: Packages for Ish**, I picked up the packages he wanted from Illium and from the Citadel, and then I delivered them to him. I then chose the paragon option of talking him into not using them, at which point he thanked me for probably saving his life and left.

[image]

However, the assignment is still open in my journal. What do I need to do to close this out? I tried talking to Aria and to Anto after talking to Ish, but neither had anything to say about it.

Comment: Have you tried reloading a previous save and completing the mission again?  I just did this mission a couple of weeks ago, completing it with the paragon option, and it closed OK for me.

Comment: This was a known issue where the entry just doesn't get greyed out in the Journal, but I unfortunately don't know whether or not it was supposed to have ever been addressed/if there's a workaround.

Comment: @RESPAWN I tried again and it still did not complete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known bug in Mass Effect 2, and as of the most recent patch/steam version, is still in effect. There is no current solution.

These are the possible paths to take when starting this mission for the first time. Bringing the package to Anto will allow the quest to properly close, but locks you into the rewards and responses from that decision - which you may not want.

From the wiki, these are your options:

> If you bring the package to Ish, you can either:
>
> - Give the packages to Ish for +50 experience, +4500 credits, and +5    Renegade points.
> - Or convince Ish he's in over his head for +40 experience, +3375    credits, and no morality points; yet the mission remains open in the
>     journal.
>
> If you bring the package to Anto (one of Aria's bodyguards in the
>   Afterlife Club) - which you can either do first or after convincing
>   Ish to leave as described above - you can either:
>
> - Give the package to Anto for +5 Paragon/Renegade points.
> - Or extort money from Anto for +40 experience, +2250 credits, and +5      Paragon/Renegade points.
>
> In either case, no one will hear from Ish ever again if the mission is
>   turned in to Anto. Should you choose the middle option of "Take care
>   of Ish", Shepard will simply suggest that Anto "clean up the mess" by
>   killing Ish, which Anto does. And if Jacob is in the squad, he finds
>   Shepard's choice to be harsh, though he still sees that Ish deserves
>   such an end. If Miranda is in the squad, she'll say that "that's
>   exactly how [she] expected Ish to go out".

Current Bioware Forum BUG thread: http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/106/index/888625/5

Comment: I just tried talking to Anto after convincing Ish to leave and it doesn't work, he just says his default line "You wanna talk?  Talk to Aria" and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind messing around with save files, there is an out-of-game solution for marking this assignment complete. You will need [Mass Effect 2 Save Editor](https://www.nexusmods.com/masseffect2/mods/170).

Not my solution. I found it [elsewhere](http://fextralife.com/forums/p5385009/packages-for-ish-hex-editing/) and it worked for me. Make backups first.

> 1. Complete the assignment with the Paragon option with Ish. This will leave the assignment open, but the summary will state both packages
>    were given to Ish.
> 2. Open the save file with the ME2 Save Editor, and open the Raw tab.
> 3. Under the "3. Plot" directory, expand ME2 Plot Table, close to the bottom locate Quest IDs
> 4. Open this and you will have an Int32 Collection Editor open listing the quest ID values associated with each quest you've acquired, in the
>    order you've acquired them. Locate the quest with **9672** as it's
>    integer, this is "Packages for Ish". In the save I was experimenting
>    with the quest was number 89, but this will depend on when you
>    acquired it.
> 5. Now open the QuestProgress table located right above QuestIDs, and find the quest number associated with the assignment, 89 in my case.
>    On the right hand side expand history.
> 6. There should only be 3 members in the bugged option, 0, 1, and 2, with 0, 1, and 2 their respective values (assuming you gave him the
>    first package). Add a new member and assign it a value of 4. This will
>    add a completed flag to the assignment and close it out in your
>    Journal.

Source: http://fextralife.com/forums/p5385009/packages-for-ish-hex-editing/

Comment: Thank you for contributing this, in 2021, the save editor can be found [here](https://www.nexusmods.com/masseffect2/mods/170), the save files on PC are at `C:\Users\username\Documents\BioWare\Mass Effect 2\Save`